# php echo not working in html

Tags: php, html, mysql, echo

This is my first code in php, so my problem might be so obvious. sorry if it is so easy :)

What I'm trying to do is that I am selecting some rows from my data base using

```
$rrows = Select ( "*" , $tbl_SubForum , null, "p");
$rrows->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'subForum');
```

I know this works fine.
Each row has the description of a sub forum, containing `title` and `id`. I am trying to show sub forum titles in table cells using this code:

```
 <table cellpadding=50px cellspacing=20px BORDER=0>
<?php
    $i=0; 
    while($rrow = $rrows->fetch()){
    var_dump($rrow);
?>
<tr>
<td class='subforum' id='subforum1'>
<?php echo $rrow["title"]; ?><br>
Sub forum manager<br>
                            
Posts: 200<br>
    Active users: 50<br>
</td>
</tr>
<?php 
    $i++;
}
                    
    ?>
```

the line `echo $rrow["title"];` doesn't work and so the page is empty, except for the result of the first `var_dump`
First `var_dump` of the first `$rrow`  shows:

[image]

as you can see, there actually is a `title` field in the array and there is only one `var_dump` so the while loop doesn't work anymore!

why is this happening?

Comment: `$rrow` is an object and not an array; try `$rrow->title` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `$rrow` is an **object** rather than an array, you have to use `$rrow->title` to access its data member.

Comment: wow YES! thank you!! I knew it was something simple that I wasn't aware of! :)